# How do you prove the following identity for the Dirac Delta Function?

Tags: dirac-delta

I'm trying to prove the following identity:

$$
\begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
x\frac{d}{dx}\delta(x)=-\delta(x)
\end{equation}
$$

I integrated both sides with respect to $x$ over the limits of $(-\infty,\infty)$ and saw that they both evaluated to $-1$.

I'm not sure if that is the right approach because the worked solution I saw multiplied both sides of the above relation by an arbitrary function $f(x)$.

Is there any reason for multiplying both sides by an arbitrary $f(x)$? I'm a little helpless here because the approach that I took seemed more direct.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118286/differential-of-dirac-delta-function

Comment: Having two functions integrate to the same thing is not enough to prove that they are equivalent. You could prove a variety of absurd things with this fact, like $\sin x = \cos x = e^x = \cdots$ with the right bounds.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks for the clarification. I guess it's simpler things like what you described that really contribute to a better foundation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definitions, for any $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R),$
$$
\langle x \delta', \varphi \rangle
= \langle \delta', x\varphi \rangle
= - \langle \delta, (x\varphi)' \rangle
= - \langle \delta, \varphi + x\varphi' \rangle
= - (\varphi + x\varphi')|_{x=0}
= -\varphi(0)
= \langle -\delta, \varphi \rangle
.
$$
Thus, $x \delta' = -\delta.$

Comment: Doesn't $\delta(x)=\infty$ at $x=0$? How were you able to get −⟨,+′⟩=−(+′) when =0?

Comment: The definition of $\delta$ is that $\langle \delta, \varphi \rangle = \varphi(0)$ for every $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R).$

Comment: Okay. I'm not completely familiar with inner products (I am still learning linear algebra). But am I correct to say that $⟨,⟩=(0)$ is analogous to $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \cdot \delta (x) dx$$?

Comment: $\delta$ is not really a function so integrals involving it are not defined. Instead it's a distribution and the application of a distribution on a test function is often written as an inner production (which it's not). But it's anyway common to treat it as a function and use it inside integrals. In this case:
$$\langle \delta, \varphi \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x)\,\varphi(x)\,dx = \varphi(0).$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying my question!